Find the distance between the incenters of the figure.
$U$ is the incenter of the triangle $DFR$ and $I$ is the incenter of the triangle $FRO$. Furthermore, $DR  \parallel UN$ and the value of the difference between the radii of the two incicles of triangles $DRO$ and $UNI$ is 4. Calculate UI. (Answer is 8.)

I tried but I can't find the solution
$UO = r: IJ = R \therefore R - r = 4 = IM$
$\angle GNF \cong \angle DBF$
NIM is cyclic
$UI^2 = R^2+NU^2 = (R-r)^2+UM^2$

(original)

No point A in the picture provided.

What do you mean by UI (S:8) ?

@Aig It would be F instead of A, I made the correction

@JeanMarie Solution=Answer = 8

I don't understand how relationship $R-r=4$ can be obtained from the fact that "ratio of inra(d)ios of triangles DRO and UNI is 4".

Is $DFR$ a right-angled triangle?

@YNK Yes, $\triangle DFR \sim \triangle DRO$

@JeanMarie  ...the arithmetic ratio between the radii of the two incicles of triangles DRO and UNI is 4: $ IJ - UG = 4 = IM$

I'd write "difference" instead of "arithmetic ratio", which is not commonly used.

In your solution you treated $IJ$ and $UG$ as if they were the inradii of $DRO$ and $UNI$, but they are not. Could we have the original figure, please?

@Intelligentipauca  HI...I used it as an arimetic ratio:
Arithmetic ratio, difference between two consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression
I would also think it would be better the way you put it

@Intelligentipauca  The website where I took the question is offline but this week it should be online again.. The figure seems to me to be from a Peruvian question where the figures are completely out of scale so I passed it on to geogebra. In the original only the internal triangle($NIU$), the right triangle($DRO$), the triangle $DRF$ and the congruent angles $O$ and$ <DRG$ are given.

Using standard techniques (see Appendix) one can verify that, whichever the shape of triangle $DRO$, segments $UN$ and $NI$ defined in the question are both equal to the inradius $x$ of $DRO$ (I suppose this is a well-known result, but I couldn't find any reference to it, at the moment).
But the inradius $x'$ of $UNI$ is then:
$$
x'={x^2\over2x+\sqrt2 x}={x\over2+\sqrt2}
$$
and we know that $x-x'=4$, which gives $x=4\sqrt2$ and finally:
$$
UI=x\sqrt2=8.
$$
APPENDIX.
Let's define: $DF=a$, $FR=b$, so that: $FO=b^2/a$, $DR=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $OR=(b/a)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $DO=(a^2+b^2)/a$.
If $r$, $R$ and $x$ are the inradii of $DFR$, $OFR$ and $DRO$ respectively, then we get (inradius is the ratio between double area and perimeter):
$$
r={ab\over a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},
\quad
R={b^2\over a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},
\quad
x={b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
$$
On the other hand, we have from similar triangles:
$$
UN:r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}:a,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
UN={b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=x
$$
and
$$
IN:R=(b/a)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}:(b^2/a),
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
IN={b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=x.
$$

Wouldn't it be $UN=NI$?

How did you calculate x'?

Yes, of course, it's a typo. I corrected and added a proof of the stated property.

$x'$ is the inradius of a right triangle with sides $x$, $x$ and $\sqrt2 x$: just apply the usual formula.

Excellent, thank's for help
